# Validate href inside a div

Tags: html, validation, fancybox, dom-events, markup

I have this type of markup:

```
<div class="box" href="pic-gallery/img01.jpg">
  <div>----------</div>
</div>
```

Now as I am going to validate this it is showing error as href inside a div is not allowed. So how to validate this error? I had used:

```
<div class="box" onclick="href='pic-gallery/img01.jpg'"></div>
```

but it is not opening the image as picture is coming through the fancybox. So please help me out. Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: First, what is it that you are trying to do? Second, from what I know `href` is not a valid attribute for a div-element.

Comment: Duplicated question with http://stackoverflow.com/q/8557938/1055987

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`href` isn't a valid attribute for `div`, just `a` and `area`. Your best bet is to use an actual link (an `a` element). You can use styling (`display: block`) to make it shown as a block on modern browsers (not, sadly, on some older versions of IE), and since its content model is [*transparent*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#transparent), you could put a div inside it. All of the examples on the [Fancybox howto page](http://fancybox.net/howto) show using an `a` element, not a `div`.

So perhaps

```
<a class="box" href="pic-gallery/img01.jpg">
  <div>----------</div>
</a>
```

...where the "box" class includes `display: block`. Or if you use that class places where you don't want block display, break out the `display: block` and apply it separately (via another class or inline `style` attribute).

Comment: ya I used that but as the image is coming in a lightbox through fancybox it is not coming like that. It is simply opening the image without lightbox.I want that lightbox.

Comment: i'd upvote this twice if i could. use the right tool for the job - with a simple display:block applied, an <a> tag can be made to act exactly like a div, styled however you like, and give you the attributes you need to use.

Comment: @newuser: I didn't catch that this was a fancybox-specific question. I've corrected your tags.

Comment: @newuser: Sure it is, follow the link on the word "transparent" above. The content model of `a` (what it's allowed to contain) is whatever the content model of its container is (with a couple of caveats around interactive elements like `audio`). So if the `a` is within a `div`, it has the same content model as a `div` and you can put another `div` inside it. If the `a` is in a `p`, which has the *[phrasing](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#phrasing-content)* content model, then you can't put it `div` in it (because you can't put a `div` in a `p`).

Answer (score 1):

With fancybox, you can show your images by putting their path inside links:

```
<a class="box" href="pic-gallery/img01.jpg"></a>
```

This will be identified by fancybox based on link's class eg `box` and will be opened by fancybox.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected - the `href` attribute is not valid on a `<div>` element. As T.J. said above, it would be best to use an actual `<a>` element to do this - it makes more semantic sense.  You could even nest the `<a>` inside the outer `<div>` and hide it with CSS, so non-JS enabled users don't see redundant markup.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code.

```
<div class="box" onclick="href='pic-gallery/img01.jpg'"></div>
```

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">function open_win(){window.open("pic-gallery/img01.jpg");}</script><div class="box" onclick="javascript:open_win();"></div>
```

But how do you want to open the image?

Comment: Actually I want the image should open in a lightbox and for lightbox I have used Fancybox.

Comment: I do not have much idea about the Lightbox or Fancybox. But, I have just provided an alternative of redirecting to a page by using the javascript onclick method instead of anchor tag like <a href="">hello</a>. It must work for any html/javascript combo.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is unusual but you could still open an image (or any other type of content) in fancybox adding the `onclick` attribute to the `<div>` (or any other tag other than the `<a>` tag) and without using the `href` attribute.

You may have this (valid) html:

```
<div class="box" onclick="openFancybox('pic-gallery/img01.jpg');">
  <div>whatever here</div>
</div>
```

and use this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openFancybox(url){
 $.fancybox({
  'href': url,
  'type': 'image' //select the proper type of content
 });
}
</script>
```

what you are doing is passing the url to the function instead of using `href`